# Android: Change App bar height of one fragment and delete text

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments

I would like to change the app bar of a certain `fragment_layout`. I would like to change the height from the default value `"56dp" to "96dp"` to fit my company logo. I also want to delete the default text.

Unfortunately, I have not found any reference to this on the Internet or have overlooked it.

I would be glad about any help.

EDIT: I know how to change the app bar height of the entire app, but that is not the question here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look to how the toolbar is declared inside a layout.

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorTextMain"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Pay attention to attributes `android:minHeight` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content`.

MinHeight attribute references itself to `?attr/actionBarSize` which has a value of 56dp.

**1)** To change the toolbar height change `android:layout_height`.

Example: `android:layout_height="300dp"`

**2)** To delete the default text, you will have to find the toolbar from code and use a method. Add this to the class where you `setContentView` of the layout containing the toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works I guess? I've declared `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` in my layout.xml but this did not changed the existing toolbar, but rather added a new one? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Have you added a toolbar programmatically? Is your activity style extending .NoActionBar?

Comment: No my AppTheme is "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar". Should I change it to .NoActionBar? But this would a lot of work to add a toolbar to every fragment..

Comment: Change it to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: But is that the best approach that is available? I mean I want to change the appbar height of one fragment and have to delete the default height of everyone else. I have over 15 fragments and this would mean I would have to add a toolbar to every fragment? And is there a way do declare a specific default appbar in one place in order to reuse it?

Comment: I don't know if this is the best approach to make a custom toolbar. But as you have stated out, reference on this argument are very poor on the internet. In terms of UI compatibilities this is for sure the best approach. There is now way as I know since every activity has a different layout.